# Replace hx-get='' with the next hx-get='' request

Tags: jinja2, htmx

I have a few projects listed from a db on my page and I get multiple 'project-update' forms if I call them one by one.

```
{% for project in user.projects.all reversed %}
    <div 
        id="project"
        hx-get="{% url 'project-update' project.pk %}"
        hx-trigger="click once"
    >
        {{ project }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The content of the 'project-update':

```
<form 
    hx-put="{% url 'project' user.username project.pk %}"
    hx-target="#projects"
>  
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
    <button hx-get="{% url 'projects' user.username %}">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

The problem is when I click Update or Cancel all of the 'project-update' opened forms are being replaced at once which makes no sense keeping a few of them opened at the same time. I want a previous form to be closed when I'm opening the next one but can't find a way to do that. Or maybe another logical solution. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "closing" a form? Visually with client side JavaScript or replacing with HTMX? Could you also share the parent template where the `#projects` element is located?

Comment: <div id="projects">
            {% include 'partials/projects.html' %}
  </div>

Inside this partial is the code I started with. 

In my case, a list of the projects is called to replace the div (with all opened forms whatever the count is). What I want to do is to cancel these forms one by one.